# Checking which Fonts are already installed

Tags: fonts

I downloaded a `.tex` file and after changing some Helvetica fonts to Times New Roman, I can finally see the `pdf`. Changing to Times New Roman was a wild guess that worked, but the result is not aesthetically pleasing. However, I didn't like the Helvetica font much either. How can I check which fonts are already installed to experiment a little? I have `Miktex 2.9` installed.

Comment: You have tagged the question metafont but none of the fonts you mention are metafont fonts. `Times New Roman` etc are usually system fonts (on Windows in that case) are you using xetex or luatex (which usually use system fonts) or pdftex which (usually) just uses specific fonts installed with TeX ?

Comment: I have little experience with fonts and thus this mistake. I am using Xelatex

Comment: Well, if you have a full installation, quite a lot — at least for tex. You also might consider compiling with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` with the `fontspec` package. This would let you easily use for text any font known to Windows. Of course, if you have maths, you should use a font matching  your math fonts. Among many, you have the `fourier + heuristica` packages (Adobe Utopia), `math-design` (Utopia again, Bitstream Charter or URW Garamond No8, that can be complemented with `garamondx`).

Comment: @Bernard. No it is plain text. I am actually searching for a family that contains both a light and a bold version. Any ideas, or personal favorites?

Comment: Since you are using XeLaTeX, you can use any font installed on your system. So whatever fonts Windows comes with these days, for example, and whatever fonts you have added. You can also use some TeX fonts, but it is simplest and most effective to use fonts installed system-wide. (Latin Modern and some others are exceptions as they have special support even if they are not installed for the OS.)

Comment: Whether you need a matching sans serif or typewriter font, whether you need small capitals and the type and content of your document are also relevant. Good choices for a letter to your bank will not be good choices for a poster advertising cough medicine.

Comment: @cfr comic sans is a good choice for any use.

Comment: Actually, I am looking for an appropriate font for a C.V.

Comment: @Paramar: Try `Minion Pro` then. It's a beautiful font that comes with Adobe Reader, and can be complemented with `Myriad Pro` if you need a matching sans serif font. If you want to buy a commercial font, my favourite is `Sabon`, a Garamond-like font designed by Jan Tschichold.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Especially for a C.V. I actually use Latin Modern for my CV. (And most other things.) I guess that is boring but since essentially none of my colleagues use it, it is not just what everyone else has. (Latex is something they make gloves and medical supplies from.)

Comment: thank you. If you want, answer my question separately so I can upvote you.

Comment: I like Garamond. If you do not need bold, EB Garamond is nice. There is a regular LaTeX version but you can also install the opentype fonts for use system-wide for easy use with XeLaTeX. I also like Palatino but I don't know if Windows has that.

Comment: @cfr Actually I have used Latin Modern again and it is great. Thank you too, for your advice.

Comment: Just remember that you do not want them to remember the font. (Unless, perhaps, you are applying for jobs as a graphic designer or something.) And it should be legible even if copied on a crappy photocopier and read by somebody with poor eyesight at 3 in the morning.